# Previous fragment state are kept in backStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app is using `FragmentTransaction` to navigate across screens. When i want to go back to the previous fragment using back button, the content of both current and previous fragment merge, and the result is pretty ugly.

For the record, here's my Transaction code :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment()); 
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Thanks

Comment: try without using `ft.addToBackStack(null);`

Comment: To use accurately moving between fragments, I recommend using TAGs for individual fragments, and load when required.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, but, since  you can't override onBackPressed in a fragment, how can i implement a correct navigation without addToBackStack ?

Comment: That's what I said, usage of TAGs. I assume you have multiple fragments, then assign each fragment a unique TAG, when ever user request's that TAG fragment, then display. If you get a `onBackPress` event then see which fragment is displayed depending on TAG and see which TAG fragment needs to displayed next.

Comment: I see, you mean adding this in the onBackPressed of the main activity ? Should do the trick, thanks